# How can I generate more images for training from few input images?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a classification network. For my classification purpose, I don't have any publicly available data set. For deep ConvNets, large number of training data is needed. It is really time consuming to create such a large data set. Is there any way to generate large number of images from  few images?
For example, 1000 images from a few 20 images for training.

If someone knows the answer, kindly help me.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use image augmentation for generating more images (for example flipping the image)

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html